# Why do python exceptions typically not print offending values?

Tags: python, exception

For instance, consider the case:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a[12]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

the exception does not print the value that was out of range.

My guess is that we don't know if the `__str__` function of whatever was passed in raises an exception, so we don't touch it?

Comment: [Here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2145593d108d/Objects/listobject.c#l185) is the offending source code. As you can see there seems to be no reason not to include `i` and `Py_SIZE(op)` in the exception message.

Comment: +1, because this is a very common issue in most programming languages. Java and C# for example both have the same issue. Even a lot of databases. Try inserting a value too large for a column in Oracle or IBM DB2, both just return an error that says "value too large for a column" but don't say what column, or what the value was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value could be printed, it just isn't.

However, there is a [tb module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tb/0.1) on PyPI that actually will print the values of the variables in the stack trace.

Comment: Why use that when the `cgitb` module already does that and it is already included. Use `cgitb.enable(format='text')` for console use.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the `__str__` method isn't an issue - if it's not supplied for an object, `__repr__` is used instead, and an any case `__repr__` would usually make more sense in an exception message.  As for the reason, I don't think there is a specific reason.  If you were to propose changing that and submitted a patch I see no reason offhand why it would be rejected.  However, actually making the change would probably be quite a massive effort because it would mean changing wherever the exception is raised.  That's actually probably the main reason it hasn't been done.  If there is a python developer around, they might be able to give a better answer...

*Edit*: Its worth pointing out that this is not the case for all exceptions. AttributeError, for example, does report the offending values.